# C++ wrapper for posix and linux specific functions

Tags: c++, linux, posix, wrapper

Do you know about any good library wrapping posix and linux functions and structures ( eg. sockets or file descriptors ) into C++ classes? For example I'm thinking about a base FileDescriptor class and some inheriting classes ( unix sockets etc ) with methods like write, read or even some syscalls ( sendfile, splice ) - all throwing exceptions instead of setting errno. Or some shared memory class etc.

I can't seem to find anything like that and by now I consider writing it myself, as I often have to write a C++ app for linux and either use C functions ( painful error checking ), or wrap them myself every time.

---EDIT---

Well neither QT nor Boost will compile on the system, we're using - it's a small linux kernel based on 2.4.29 installed on embedded computers.

Comment: Why wrapping something if it is not intended to be cross-platform? Besides, C error handling isn't nearly as painful as ensuring exception safety in C++ code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Common C++](http://www.gnu.org/software/commoncpp/). I haven't used it myself, but it supports the things you've mentioned.

Comment: That should be what I'm looking for, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Well, not exactly a wrapper, but [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs) has a [library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) [for](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) [everything](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/thread.html), and supports all major platforms.

Answer (score 4):

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/) has a number of portable interfaces for some of the things you need e.g. [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) or [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

Answer (score 2):

[posixcpp](https://bitbucket.org/starling13/posixcpp/). It is at early stage now. It isn't crossplatform, but GCC and Linux oriented. Licensed under LGPL 3.

Answer (score 1):

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products) tackles many of the problems which normally are platform dependent. GUI wise, but console stuff is covered too.
e.g.:

- http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qtnetwork.html
- http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qtcore.html
- http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qfile.html

Answer (score 0):

There's [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) - which is much more than a GUI library. Nokia call it "application and UI framework". The "application" part refers to Qt's wrapping of interfaces for files, sockets, threads, and much more.

Qt is C++, and IMHO one of the best designed C++ code bases out there, so it's definitely worth a try.