# Is there any function in c++ that can create a process replace the current process like function execve() in C？

Tags: c++, posix

In C programming language, I use `execve()` to replace the current process. I feel confused that how to do the same work in C++?

Comment: There should be no problem with calling execve() within C++ code. After C++ is compatible with C. What exactly confuses you?

Comment: At present, my projects do not use C programming language, they are all written in C++, so I want to try to use C++, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Again: C++ can execute (almost) any C code. You don't have to do anything special. You include the header and call it, just like in C.

Comment: You can easily have a C++ declaration of `execve`, e.g. `extern "C" { #include <unistd.h> }`. Then all you need to do is provide a suitable object file to your linker so it can link to it.

Comment: If you insist on using C++ code instead of C, you might check: [C++ wrapper for posix and linux specific functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543996/c-wrapper-for-posix-and-linux-specific-functions)

Comment: `execve` is a syscall and like all syscalls does not have a C++ specific version